Django server throwing a MultiValueDictKeyError even though the value of the parameter is present
I have a Django endpoint that runs a query that updates a row in my database using the image_name. I am storing that image name in the client session storage and retrieving it and sending it to the endpoint. The endpoint then runs the function upload_to_db() on the data and returns success or failure based on the updating of the database. The problem is, this function is continuously throwing me a MultiValueDictKeyError error over the image name specifically in this line:
img_name = request.POST["image_name"]
Despite this, the function is running and the values get updated as needed but I still get this error.
class paymentClass(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "payment.html")

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST["email"]
        pid = request.POST["pid"]
        img_name = request.POST["image_name"]
        # if not all([email, pid, img_name]):
        #     body = {"errorMessage": "Missing parameters"}
        #     return JsonResponse(body, status=400)
 
        result = upload_to_db(email, img_name, pid)
        print(result)
        if result == "success":
            return JsonResponse({"message": "created successfully", "image_name": img_name}, status=201)
        else:
            body = {"errorMessage": result}
            return JsonResponse(body, status=400)

Edit:
Here is the upload_to_db function if that helps:
def upload_to_db(email, name, pay_id):
with connection.cursor() as conn:
    conn.execute("UPDATE asowinUsersUS set email = %s, p_id = %s WHERE image_name = %s", (email, pay_id, name))
    if conn.rowcount > 0:
        return 'success'
    else:
        return 'failed'

I have tried printing the image name, which shows the right name. I have made sure that the image is passed on to the server correctly as well.
The problem seems to be in line:
img_name = request. POST["image_name"]

This endpoint works fine on PostMan so I dont even know how to debug it.
I'm sending the request using fetch function with the data as formData.
This is the code:
function submitPaymentDetails() {
  var email = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
  var pay = document.getElementById('userPay').value;
  var img_name = sessionStorage.getItem('image_name').valueOf();
  var formData = new FormData();
  
  formData.append('email', email);
  formData.append('pid', pay);
  formData.append('image_name', img_name);
  var url = "/payment/";

  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
  })
  .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 201) {
          return response.json();
      } else {
          throw new Error('Payment details submission failed');
      }
  })
  .then(data => {
      window.location.href = '/thank/';
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  });
}

Here is the complete error traceback:
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/

Django Version: 5.0.4
Python Version: 3.11.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'asowin_images',
 'us_users',
 'asowin_users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 84, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

During handling of the above exception ('image_name'), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\asowin_images\views.py", line 86, in post
    img_name = request.POST["image_name"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\asowin\usbackend\usEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /payment/
Exception Value: 'image_name'


Please add the upload to bd func code and also, a print not only of the "img_name" post value, but also a print of what type of data it is so we can check.

@jsanchezs This is the upload_to_db function:
'def upload_to_db(email, name, pay_id):
with connection.cursor() as conn:
conn.execute("UPDATE asowinUsersUS set email = %s, p_id = %s WHERE image_name = %s", (email, pay_id, name))
if conn.rowcount > 0:
return 'success'
else:
return 'failed'
'
This returns success even when the code throws the error.
img_name like all others in the request are strings.

Please specify how you are making that request. Also you seem to be using Django Rest Framework are you sure you shouldn't be using request.data instead of request.POST?

"Despite this, the function is running and the values get updated as needed" Are you sure you're really getting an error? If you were getting an error at the line you say you are the update you speak of won't be happening. Share the complete error traceback.

@AbdulAzizBarkat yes the data is being updated.
I've updated the post to show entire error traceback
